# Azure web jobs - determining deployment slot

Tags: python, powershell, azure

I am trying to create a web job running in Azure in either Powershell or Python that can determine which deployment slot it's running in and report it back to me.  we plan on having the same code run in multiple slots and would like it to know where it's actually running.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

well, easiest way of doing so is creating an environment variable in the web app and reading it with your code. That way you can easily determine where you are running.

**python**: os.getenv('bla')
**powershell**: $env:bla

> App settings
>
> This section contains name/value pairs that you web app will load on
>   start up. For .NET apps, these settings are injected into your .NET
>   configuration AppSettings at runtime, overriding existing settings.
>   PHP, Python, Java and Node applications can access these settings as
>   environment variables at runtime. For each app setting, two
>   environment variables are created; one with the name specified by the
>   app setting entry, and another with a prefix of APPSETTING_. Both
>   contain the same value.

Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure#application-settings

Comment: I thought of that, but the slots gets swapped fairly often so I wouldn't always know when environment variable is which.

Comment: that doesn't make a lot of sense, variables are scoped to slots

Comment: yeah it looks like that's the solution we're pursuing. thanks and pardon my ignorance...new to azure.